# string substitution regular expression not working in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

i am trying to replace all the special characters including white space, hyphen, etc, to underscore, from a string variable in tcl.

> Example
>
> > ```
> >     input: Stack Overflow helps%me(a lot
> >     output: Stack_Overflow_helps_me_a_lot
> > ```

I wrote the code below but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    set varname $origVar
    puts "Variable Name :>> $varname"
    if {$varname != ""} {
        regsub -all {[\s-\]\[$^?+*()|\\%&#]} $varname "_" $newVar
    }
    puts "New Variable :>> $newVar"
```

one issue is that, instead of replacing the string in $varname, it is deleting the data after first space encountered inside $origVar instead of $varname. Also there is no value stored in $newVar. No idea why, and also i read the example code (for proper syntax) in my tcl book and according to that it should be something like this

```
    regsub -all {[\s-][$^?+*()|\\%&#]} $varname "_" newVar
```

so i used the same syntax but it didn't work and gave the same result as modifying the $origVar instead of required $varname value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version is closer. By putting the result in `$newVar` you're actually setting a variable named whatever is stored *in* `$newVar`, *i.e.* you would then have to access it by `$$newVar`, so to speak (not valid in Tcl). Anyway, the issue is probably that in your second version, you don't seem to be escaping certain characters. Try this:

```
regsub -all {[\s\-\]\[$^?+*()|\\%&#]} $varname "_" newVar
```

Another way to organize that to minimize escaping is this:

```
regsub -all {[][\s$^?+*()|\\%&#-]} $varname "_" newVar
```

And, I don't know if this is too general, but you can try this too:

```
regsub -all {\W} $varname "_" newVar
```

Comment: Well the second option worked fine for me. i did not try the first one. although the third option will replace all the non alpha-numeric characters which will even include '_' which i think is shouldn't even be considered. Thanks for the information you gave.

Comment: Note that `\w` includes digits, so `[^\w\d]` is a bit redundant. Simpler is to replace all non-word chars with `regsub -all {\W} $var "_" new` -- see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Comment: Also note that `regsub` (since 8.4) returns the replaced string if you don't specify a variable; I find that really convenient when I don't need to know the number of replacements made (which is 0/1 except when `-all` is used).

Comment: @glennjackman - Thanks for the correction; edited. (I use Tcl 8.0.5, which has no such shortcut classes, so sometimes I forget their contents.)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the `string map` command, which is simpler: the string map command takes in a list of old/new and a string:

```
set varname [string map {% _ ( _ " " _} $varname]
```

In the above example, for the sake of brievity, I only replaced %, (, and space " " with an underscore. The disadvantage of this solution is the old/new list can be somewhat long. The advantage is easier to understand.